# How to check multiple sql queries in same sql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to check multiple sql queries if one is false then second query running, if second wrong then third run. how to do that. i am so confused.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(u.`global`) 
        FROM user u 
        WHERE u.global = user.user_id AND launch=1 )as done , user_id  
FROM user HAVING done < 6
```

if this false then run this sql query:-

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(u.`global`) 
     FROM user u 
     WHERE u.global = user.user_id AND launch=1 )as done , user_id  
FROM user HAVING done > 7
```

Comment: I see in your tags that you use PHP.
Then you just need to check if the statement was executed : $stmt->execute() ; if ($stmt) { }

Comment: I think this is only possible if you create mysql procedure within `if` statement. Or put this logic in php.

Comment: Yeah @DanMiller you are right how to do that ?? :(

Answer (score 0):

You could  use a siplle count grouo by user and use  OR   ( and group by)   for check the two having condition

```
 SELECT COUNT(u.`global`) done,  u.user_id
 from user u
 group by user_id
 having  done <6 or done >7
```